# Should one use an Activity or a Service when using a button in a Widget?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, listener, android-appwidget

I'm been trying to figure this out for a while now, and have just become more and more confused.

I have made a Android Widget which displays two articles (title + image). In addition to this, I have buttons for flipping backward and forward through the articles. What I don't understand is how I can change the Widgets RemoteViews when the buttons are pressed. Which should be one of the most basic operations in a widget, however, I can't seem to figure it out.

So...

- Can I do this with just a OnClickListener in the AppWidgetProvider?
- Or do I have to create an Activity without a window (visibility = false)?

Please excuse my stupidity. This is probably very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is basic at all - it's something I thought about for a while in relation to the Headset Blocker app I wrote, which is just a widget that you toggle on/off.

I ended up looking through Google's source code for what they did.  The answer is to use the AppWidget's receiver nature to receive updates via [`setOnClickPendingIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setOnClickPendingIntent(int,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).  Then in `onReceive()`, you react differently to your own clicks than someone trying to create a widget.  [You can see a sample of what I did in the Headset Blocker source](http://code.google.com/p/android-headset-blocker/source/browse/trunk/src/com/idunnolol/headsetblocker/ToggleWidgetProvider.java).

Ultimately, an Activity or a Service is too heavy weight for what you want.  Using the same BroadcastReceiver as the app widget itself is much better.

Comment: "Ultimately, an Activity or a Service is too heavy weight for what you want." -- that depends on what you're doing. Bear in mind that `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` is called on the main application thread. If you are going to do significant work on that thread (more than, say, 300ms), you should seriously consider delegating that work to an `IntentService`, so that work can be done with background priority on a background thread.

Comment: True enough.  I guess it depends on whether the title + image are retrieved when the user clicks the widget or if it's cached ahead of time.